# JSF Rerender not effective until page refresh

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces, rerender

I have a check box, on which a datatable id is given as rerender. Here is  the complete tag of the check box from JSP-

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="A_IsDefaultSpouseAnnutant"
    value="#{XXXXXX.a_IsDefaultSpouseAnnutant}">
    <a4j:support actionListener="#{XXXXXX.changeVisibility}" ajaxSingle="true"
        event="onclick" immediate="true" reRender="benListTable"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

My expectation is that on clicking on the check box, the datatable below should rerender and show the changed values. But the changes are not effective until I manually refresh the page. I searched over internet for any causes of this problem but couldn't find any. Any ehlp would be greatly helpful.

**Note: The table is disabled when I am trying to reRender. Does JSF reRender disabled elements?**

Comment: What happens if you reRender the parent component of the `DataTable` instead of the table itself?

Comment: Parent component? Example? Also please see my edit.

Comment: A parent component is the component of which the datatable is a child, e.g. in which the datatable is nested. If you don't have an obvious one, just wrap it into a `panelGroup`. Does the re-rendering always work exactly after the 3rd time? Or is it sometimes the 4th time, and sometimes the 8th time, etc?

Comment: it always works exactly after 3rd time.

Comment: What happens if you build a simpler example with just the select box and action listener, without all the javascript in the `onsubmit` handler? *(for the example here, remove the styling as well, that's a lot of noise that potential answerers may not feel like to wade through)*

Comment: I tried removing all those extra properties, still, it isn't working.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 or JSF 2.x?